# AngularJS, directive element is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dom

I'm working on porting a jQuery plugin to AngularJS just because it seems fun.
In the past, when using jQuery, I was using jQuery to manipulate the DOM. So, I have a function in jQuery to load the plugin and in that function is was maniuplating the DOM.

Now, when using AngularJS, I've read that there are `directives` for that specific purpose, but I don't manage to find the solution.

I have the following html:

```
<body class="officeui-space-no-margin officeui-space-no-padding">
    <!-- Defines the OfficeUI section. In this section, all the contents for the OfficeUI user interface will be written. -->
    <div ng-controller="OfficeUIController" id="OfficeUI">
        <div class="title officeui-align-center">
            <span>Here the title can go.</span>
        </div>

        <!-- Defines the main holder for the ribbon. -->
        <div id="ribbonHolder">
            <!-- Render the template for the ribbon. -->
            <ng-include src="'Partials/Templates/Ribbon/tabs.html'"></ng-include>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bottom scripts: Used for Initialization. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Initialize the 'ribbonHolder' element as a ribbon.
        $('#ribbonHolder').ribbon();
    </script>
</body>
```

You see here that I'm loading a template to render, of which the contents can be found below:

```
<ul role="tablist" class="officeui-space-no-margin officeui-space-no-padding">
    <!-- Render all the tabs in the collection. -->
    <tabs-container>
        <li role="tab" class="officeui-display-inline-block officeui-align-center" ng-repeat="tab in tabs">{{tab.Name|tabs}}</li>
    </tabs-container>
</ul>
```

In the template above, I do have an element `tabs-container` which should be my directive.
I've the JavaScript that defines the AngularJS stuff, including registering this directive:

```
var officeUIApplication = angular.module('OfficeUI.Ribbon.Controllers', []);
officeUIApplication.directive('tabsContainer', function() {
    var functionLink = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(element.children());
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: functionLink
    };
});
```

According to my very limited knowledge of AngularJS, I'm just learning it, it's in the variable `functionLink` where I should manipulate the DOM of attach event handlers to specific parts.

But inside `functionLink` I call the following code:

```
console.log(element.children());
```

But in the console I do see that this particular element is empty.
Why is that, and is this the good approach?

Another approach of which I've tought it to include something in jQuery so that the code is only executed after AngularJS has finished it's work, but I don't like that particular idea, on the other hand, how do I create a jQuery plugin that that passes options and event handlers, or isn't that possible anymore and am I in fact creating an AngularJS plugin?

Thanks for the response.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
officeUIApplication.directive('tabsContainer', function($timeout) {
    var functionLink = function(scope, element, attrs) {
         $timeout(function() { 
              element.ribbon();
         });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: functionLink
    };
});
```

jQuery plugins usually require the DOM to be ready for it to initialize properly.  In angular, there is no real concept of DOM ready.  $timeout is executed after the render phase, which is why it works.

Comment: You mind explaining what this changed, I see I've passed a parameter $timeout right now, but don't understand why this is needed. Also, element.children() is not null, but running a jQuery selector on it don't return any elements :s

Comment: Ok, that makes a bit more sense, but event inside the AngularJS timeout function, I cannot manipulate the dom, if I call the method element.ribbon as you've showed above, then it's working, why is that? Why can't I execute selectors inside the directive?

Comment: Its because the DOM is not ready. try doing a angular.element(document).ready(function() { element.ribbon(); }); from inside your link function. That should work too.  But if you want to update UI elements when the model changes, then use $timeout instead

Comment: Ok, that makes a bit more clear, just one additional question, Have a look at the following fiddle: why are there elements inside here and in my original code not? http://jsfiddle.net/E7xER/891/

Comment: jQuery selectors are reliable within a link function. If it is not working, something else is going on.

Comment: Not necessary anymore. It's working right now. Is it a good approach to execute a jQuery plugin from withing an AngularJS directive?

Comment: Angular execute the link function when the element is rendered. The $timeout has no effect. You get an empty element because the directive has not a template defined, and no `transclude` option in order to write custom inner html.

Comment: I would say yes. Its acceptable.  Sometimes though, its just as easy to convert the jquery plugin to an angular plugin

Comment: @marquez, mmm, you sure about that? If I could down-vote your comment, I would

Comment: @marquez If I remove the timeout function, nothing is working so I don't know if your assumption is correct.

Comment: You are getting a result because you are calling the `ribbon()` plugin on the element but `$timeout` is useless. You can get the same result without it. The point is another one. In your example you call the `children` method on the directive element, and the reason why you get an empty element is because the directive replace all it's content with a template or whatever you put through the `link` function. You have not a template. And `<li>` child is ignored without the `transcude` option. The solution could work but has a wrong assumption. Here an example: http://goo.gl/jJ4MIS

Comment: good sir, he has no template in his directive definition. So transclude does not apply. And the element's children will not be cleared out either - again because he has no template, and he's not using transclusion.